# replace comma followed by a character by semicolon while keeping the same character

Tags: r, regex

Provided a vector like this: `test = "Education & research,Non-Profit (NGOs, foundations, associations...),Government (local, regional, national),Individuals,Other"` I would like to replace all commas that are followed by alhpa character (not space) **while preserving original alpha character**, so I can later split multiple values within a cell by splitting by semicolon.

So far, I have used the following code:

```
> gsub(",\\S", ";", test)
[1] "Education & research;on-Profit (NGOs, foundations, associations...);overnment (local, regional, national);ndividuals;ther"
```

As you can see, I have replaced all commas (that's fine!) but I also deleted the first letter of the word following them! (that's wrong!). I get the same result if I type `gsub(",[A-Z]", ";", test)`

That's why I tried with

```
> gsub(",[A-Z]", ";[A-Z]", test)
[1] "Education & research;[A-Z]on-Profit (NGOs, foundations, associations...);[A-Z]overnment (local, regional, national);[A-Z]ndividuals;[A-Z]ther"
```

But the replacement doesn't seem to accept `[A-Z]` as replacement token for the original character.

Is there any way to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: `gsub(",(\\S)", ";\\1", test)`

Comment: [`,(?=[A-Z])` replace with `;`](https://regex101.com/r/BTbaE4/1)

Comment: @G5W, your comment worked like charm. I had already read about using groups but I forgot one backslash when typing `\\1`.  Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Brief

You can use a positive lookahead. **Positive lookaheads** assert that the given subpattern can be matched at that position **without consuming characters**.

Regex replacements are fairly literal in how they replace. So, as you've seen, a replacement of `;[A-Z]` is literally used. Another way to achieve what you want is to make the next character part of a capture group such that your regex becomes `,([A-Z])` and you use the replacement of `;$1` (here `$1` is a reference to the most recently matched text inside capture group 1). Although it's possible with groups, it's usually better to use assertions for things you don't actually want to replace (in this case the uppercase character) as my answer provides below.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/BTbaE4/1/)

```
,(?=[A-Z])
```

For Unicode support you can use `,(?=\p{Lu})`. `\p{Lu}` means any uppercase character in any script/language. This will match, for example, `É` whilst `[A-Z]` will not.

Replacement: `;`

#### Usage

```
gsub(",(?=[A-Z])",";","Education & research,Non-Profit (NGOs, foundations, associations...),Government (local, regional, national),Individuals,Other", perl=TRUE)
```

**Note**: This regex uses a positive lookahead and, as such, `gsub` requires `perl=TRUE` to be passed.

---

### Results

#### Input

> Education & research,Non-Profit (NGOs, foundations,
>   associations...),Government (local, regional,
>   national),Individuals,Other

#### Output

```
Education & research;Non-Profit (NGOs, foundations, associations...);Government (local, regional, national);Individuals;Other
```

---

### Explanation

- `,` Match a literal comma
- `(?=[A-Z])` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches an uppercase ASCII letter

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It was really useful and I learnt a lot with it. I am not yet accepting it because unfortunately, I haven't been able to make it work. `> gsub(",(?=[A-Z])", ";", test)` results in this error `Error in gsub(",(?=[A-Z])", ";", test) : 
  invalid regular expression ',(?=[A-Z])', reason 'Invalid regexp'`

Comment: @ccamara It's because you need to set `perl=TRUE`. See my edit under the **Usage** section for more information and a sample command.

Comment: Thank you for further explanation! I didn't know about the `perl=TRUE`. It is working perfectly now.